# What process of torrenting is recognised by ISP

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, bittorrent

Suppose I wanted to download a torrent file (which is not approved of by my home ISP).

On the other hand, there is no issues downloading using my Mobile Data (3G).

Could I connect to my Mobile Data using a Hotspot, begin the download, and when I'm 5% through, switch back to my original home wifi?

This way the process using the torrent website, downloads the torrent file, is all done on my mobile network.

After this point can my ISP recognise what it is exactly that I'm downloading?

Comment: Of course they can, unless you are using encrypted connection (which torrent does not do). But I don't think that this is legal at least in the European Union. They can do automated traffic shaping, though, which would block torrenting. You could get a VPN-account - which then uses encryption - and your torrenting would be undetecable.

Comment: Your isp can sniff all your packets to see that is being downloaded, but I doubt they spend resources doing this. Most of the time they get a notice from the copyright holder, copyright holder can identify what torrents you are downloading and the source ip, which is what gets reported to the isp, then the isp notifies you to stop it. Yes use a vpn service to cloak your traffic and your ip address.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you understand how torrents work.  The 'download' happens the WHOLE time, not 'the website' you use to get the torrent magnet/file.

Your ISP shouldn't be monitoring your website usage, so getting a torrent magnet link or .torrent file won't be the issue.

The issue would be the traffic pattern that is typical with torrents (large amounts of connections and increase in traffic) when you queue up the torrent for download in your favorite client (utorrent, etc;)

If you have concerns use a VPN or proxy to hide your traffic, most torrent clients support full encryption over VPN/socks proxy.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the ISP knowing **that** I'm torrenting. The problem is the ISP knowing **what** I'm torrenting.

Comment: that and what are not relevant here, as one leads into the other.  They typically traffic match and then they can determine what you are doing and from where.  Again using VPN/proxy will hide that traffic pattern.

Comment: So your question was unclear. Because there are many torrents that offer legal stuff. So in that case it would just be your provider who doesn't allow.

Comment: @TJJ Sorry for the confusion. I'll get a VPN set up.

Comment: Ok. Just that I doubt there is ANY ISP in the world that approves downloading of illegal material ^^

Comment: @Jakub - Its only a problem if the copyright owner of the data being downloaded contacts the ISP about the user download said data.  You are right an ISP itself doesn't really care, it might throttle your data, thats done with Deep Packet Inspection though.